# Is there a good way to document Spring @Value fields?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Over the course of writing Spring Boot apps, our team adds in a lot of `@Value` annotations to help make things configurable. At some point we start to lose track of exactly what we added and what can be configured. We get a lot of questions from the QA and DevOps teams about what exactly can be configured and what can't.

Currently we just do a grep through the code base and apply some crude regular expressions to try and parse out the meaningful pieces. But this doesn't catch 100% of cases and inevitably we end up digging through the code to find out what fields can be configured.

I know we could use JavaDoc to somewhat achieve our goal, but the documentation would be buried with other JavaDoc (methods, fields, classes, etc) and it's still reliant on developers to remember to add the JavaDoc to each field.

Has anyone found a more automated way to document their `@Value` fields? I'm thinking something like Swagger, but specifically for Spring and the various ways it can externalize configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc is indeed a way to document for developers, not the QA or the operators. 
Your question is really interesting but answering to that canonically is hard because `@Value` are **implementation details** of components. Swagger that you quote documents REST **contracts**, that is an important difference.

Here some ideas :

- Writing a BDD test for them that could be used too as documentation makes really no sense functionally but technically it makes. 
  Indeed, you could write a BDD integration test (with Cucumber or any other library) where you document and test the presence of each expected property.
- Not a perfect solution, but you could at least retrieve exposed properties and a little more with [these Spring Boot actuators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) :

> `configprops` : Displays a collated list of all @ConfigurationProperties.
>
> `env` : Exposes properties from Spring’s ConfigurableEnvironment.

- Whenever you can, favor `@ConfigurationProperties` injection to group properties that work together rather than `@Value`. Isolating them in `@ConfigurationProperties` classes and adding javadoc for them is not bad at all to document their presence and usage.
- as suggested by `caco3` you can also generate [your own metadata by using the Annotation Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) :

> You can easily generate your own configuration metadata file from
>   items annotated with @ConfigurationProperties...
>
> **The processor picks up both classes and methods that are annotated
>   with @ConfigurationProperties**. **The Javadoc for field values** within
>   configuration classes **is used to populate the description attribute**.

It joins with the previous point : favoring `@ConfigurationProperties` whenever it is possible.

Comment: Also with `@ConfigurationProperties` you can generate a json file with description of the properties declared inside. See [Generating Your Own Metadata by Using the Annotation Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor). And also this link: https://jakubstas.com/configuration-meta-data-in-spring-boot/

Comment: @caco3  That is an excellent point to complement the `@ConfigurationProperties` point.

Comment: Yes, that will work out greatly for the OP, I think, if they do not use SPeL inside `@Value`

Comment: Thanks for this answer and good call on the `configprops` and `env` actuators; we do use them but they don't meet all of our needs. Some of our apps are simple command line tools that run for a short period of time (i.e. they inject some test data and terminate), and so they don't have actuator enabled and don't run long enough to query.

Comment: You are welcome. I understand. You have also the classical way that Spring Boot uses : defining a properties (or multiple) with all usable properties and a comment associated to: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you only use the `@Value` annotation with a property name, there will be no generated spring-configuration-metadata.json file even if you attach the required dependency (`spring-boot-configuration-processor`).

To make sure they land in that file you must create a so called `additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` file where you can write those properties that are only being used by the `@Value` annotation. The format is the same as the spring-configuration-metadata.json file's.

After that you can use this tool to create fancy AsciiDoc, Markdown, HTML or XML based documentation for your configuration properties. With that bigger projects will have some overview about their configuration.

https://github.com/rodnansol/spring-configuration-property-documenter

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your question, but this is very much the problem why I created Jamal (https://github.com/verhas/jamal).

Jamal is a preprocessor that processes Jamal macros in your documentation. If you use Markdown, then you can edit your documentation in `mydoc.md.jam`. If it is Asciidoc then `mydoc.adoc.jam`. The preprocessor will generate the `mydoc.(md|adoc)` file when it runs. It can continuously run as the IntelliJ Asciidoctos plugin preprocessor, but it can also run as a Maven plugin.

For the issue, you have what I usually do is that I insert the documentation into comments right before or after the documented line. You can also enclose the comments between `// snippet XXX` and `//end snippet` lines where `XXX` is a unique id. After that you can include the snippet in your document using a macro, do some regular-expression-based translation and it will get properly formatted into your Markdown or Asciidoc file.

The idea, which for me at least works, that you are less likely to forget to write the documentation in the code than in a separate documentation file.

The macros are quite powerful, you can write simple "programs" to check that the number of snippets is the same as the number of `@Value` annotations. You can also refer to snippet names using regular expressions, so you do not need to list each in your document separately.

Have a look at it. You may like it and if you happen to do so and start using it, let me know.